# Generic function getting optional property value with default value

Tags: typescript

There is an object type like below `X`. Note that all properties are optional, their types are different, and for some properties, `null` is a valid value.

```
type X = {
  a?: number | null;
  b?: string;
  c?: boolean | null;
};
```

Now, for convenience, I want to make a function to get one of the `X`'s property values.
The function can accept a default value and return it if the property is missing.

The function I wrote is below:

```
function get<K extends keyof X>(k: K, x: X, defaultValue: Required<X>[K]): Required<X>[K] {
  const v = x[k];
  return v !== undefined ? v : defaultValue;
}
```

Because the properties are optional, I used `Required<X>[K]` to get the valid property type (excluding `undefined`).

My expected results are:

```
// a: number | null = 12345
const a = get('a', {}, 12345);
// b: string = 'bar'
const b = get('b', { b: 'bar' }, '?');
// c: boolean | null = null
const c = get('c', {}, null);
```

But I got the following compiler error at the return statement of the `get` function.

```
Type 'Required<X>[K] | (X[K] & ({} | null))' is not assignable to type 'Required<X>[K]'.
  Type 'X[K] & null' is not assignable to type 'Required<X>[K]'.
    Type 'X[K] & null' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I guess there is a mistake in the function (probably around the use of `Required`), but I can't solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are testing for `v !== undefined` TypeScript will narrow the type of `v` to `X[K] & ({} | null)`. This intersection type, excludes undefined from the value type using an intersection.

`Required<X>[K]` does a similar thing, but there is actually a corner case where it does not remove `undefined` from `K`, when the property type includes `undefined`, but the property is not optional:

```
//number | undefined
type XX = Required<{ o: undefined | number }>['o']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTB2FcFsCMFMCcAEAfR5QBNYDMCWpYMAoAFwE8AHWRADRsQF5EAlWAR3F3kIB4BvRAHsAXGkw58hFIggwEiAL4A+ANoByQWoC6QA)

Even though `Required<X>[K]` is more permissive than `X[K] & ({} | null)` (allowing `X[K] - optional undefined`) TypeScript will not be able to follow the mapped type to arrive at this conclusion.

The simplest solution would be to define a `NotUndefined` undefined that is similar to how TypeScript excludes `undefined` from `v` that we can use for both the return value and for the `defautlValue` parameter:

```
type NotUndefined<T> = T & ({} | null)

function get<K extends keyof X>(k: K, x: X, defaultValue: NotUndefined<X[K]>): NotUndefined<X[K]>  {
  const v = x[k];
  return v !== undefined ? v : defaultValue;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoKUCGB+AXFAdgK4C2ARhAE5QA+BhANvQNxpSm5QDOwFAlvgHMW6AMYdSAewn0IGfDTqNhUACZ5J02fNpFGCwvhUQAZvwgqWAXxYpQkKADkJwAKqGTZlQB4AKgD4EKB8oADIoAAokSwVdegBKFBRjAxFgXgl5AQhgLwBpKAgAD2AIQ04oAGsIEAljWD9wirxcgBooQrwYNqNjDAZgADUMekIIPCdXd1N8cy8YAG1cgF0-OPHnNx7POcWV9FRRDO4oADdAwvmKpeUKbMIKeTOAQnhEAy2ZlSgsU6g8Hr69EGw1GVkSAHpwZg8EQyJQYgx6IEAIwAJgAzAAWACsKBER2AmECWWA4QA5BgyW0kKo-lBevROBBLG00VjsXEWJC2HhuHxBIEyaQMBQyXiCWxidlyaQqcgeVAhSK5V88AymVAWYqsGTOShuSJ1FIZHIEXpELFxfhjiIpaSySI5TTVfThhqtbE9RCoRNMIwJAB3cwFE6lKDAAAWEkIAgjtOG9ED5XeHk+VuOX0QJPJKidtLVbugWpT03MeqAA)

The version above does not allow `undefined` for the default value if the property was required and it had `undefined` explicitly in it's type (ex `{ d: boolean | null | undefined; }`).

You could preserve the original behavior, by reverting `defaultValue` back to `Required<X>[K]` and adding it in a union with `NotUndefined<X[K]>` to the return type:

```
function get<K extends keyof X>(k: K, x: X, defaultValue: Required<X>[K]): Required<X>[K] | NotUndefined<X[K]>  {
  const v = x[k];
  return v !== undefined ? v : defaultValue;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)